# Mootools AJAX post form

Tags: ajax, mootools

I am using mootools for the first time to do an AJAX call with method "post". 
I would like to capture the data from the form. first name, email and checkbox)

Is there something similar to the jQuery form.serialize()?

```
$('submit').addEvent('click', function(event) {
        var req = new Request({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'url.php',
            data: ,
            onSuccess: function(response) {
               alert(response);
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Form.toQueryString](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3atoQueryString) or if you include "more" you can use [Form Request](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Request)